# Create (nested) List from two Lists in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, nested-lists

I would like to create an Array from two Arrays but I do not want to create this new Array, with append() or extend().

Input arrays have the same number of rows and columns:

```
listone = [1,2,3]
listtwo = [4,5,6]
```

Outcome we expect:

```
mergedlist = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

It can't be done via

```
mergedlist = listone.append(listtwo) or mergedlist = listone.extend(listtwo)
```

I would like to get

```
mergedlist = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: Please don't use the term [`array`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) when you have a `list`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the builtin `zip` function. It's exactly what you want. From the python manuals:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> zipped
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Or if you want a list of lists, instead of a list of tuples, you use `zip` with a list comprehension:

```
>>> zipped = [list(t) for t in zip(x, y)]
>>> zipped
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: Thank you!! I check it. I can not put +1 because not have 15. But more thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Even if you can't vote up, you can always accept whichever answer worked for you by clicking the check mark near the score. You get a couple of reputation points for accepting an answer as well, and it encourages people to answer your questions in the future.

Comment: Nigel also has another answer below which should work. It uses `map` instead of list comprehensions. If it matters, you can test to see which is faster.

Comment: For what it's worth, I did a very quick test, and using the list comprehension is every so slightly faster than using `map`. Running each example ten million times, it took not quite one second longer to do it with `map` (about 5% longer).

Comment: With two dimensions elements one = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]] and two = [[2,5],[6,7],[6,7]]  Outcome we expect: result =[[1,4,2,5],[2,5,6,7],[3,6,6,7]] it is the same?

Comment: You can run the python interactive shell to find out.

Comment: Thank you. I find http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy librarys to work with arrays. My problem is that I have 63 arrays of dimensions 32,14 ... I need more control.

Comment: the question asks for arrays but uses lists. How would  you do this with numpy.array object?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
listone = [1,2,3]
listtwo = [4,5,6]

merged = map(list, zip(listone, listtwo))
```

`zip(listone, listtwo)` will return a list of tuples. Since you want a list of lists you need to convert each tuple to a list. `map(list, list_of_tuples)` call will do exactly that.

Comment: It returns a map object in Python 3.9, must be converted to list with a list(map...)